# User-declared namespace member

Tags: c++, namespaces

There is from 3.4.1/14:

> If a variable member of a namespace is defined outside of the scope of
>   its namespace then any name that appears in the definition of the
>   member (after the declarator-id) is looked up as if the definition of
>   the member occurred in its namespace.

**If that name treated as the definition of the member name then what is it point of declaration?**

And why the following example will works:

```
namespace N 
{
    extern int j;
}
int i = 2;
int N::j = i; //N::j=2
```

`int N::j=i` actual appears into the namespace scope. Hence the declaration`int i=2` is not visible for unqualified name lookup. **Why does this declaration found?**

Comment: Why do you think `::i` is not visible?

Comment: Name lookup is allowed to look *outside* the current namespace -- it is not allowed to look *inside* other namespaces.

Comment: What version of the standard are you looking at? N3696 contains an `int i = 4;` defined within namespace `N`, and `N::j` is initialized to `4`, not `2`. Edit: Oh, you're asking why this also works. Because names in the global namespace are also visible for unqualified lookup.

Comment: @Praetorian: Not just that - any name "above" the current namespace is searched by unqualified lookup, right?

Comment: @KerrekSB I asked why unqualified name lookup in the namespace scope can find a declaration outside after that namespace?

Comment: @KerrekSB Can you explain what does `If a variable member of a namespace is defined outside of the scope of its namespace then any name that appears in the definition of the member (after the declarator-id) is looked up as if the definition of the member occurred in its namespace.` mean? What is the sense of it?

Comment: @CTAHOK3ABXO3A Don't think of `i` as being defined *outside* namespace `N`, but *within the enclosing namespace* (since the global namespace can be considered to be an enclosing namespace for all user-defined namespaces). 3.4.1/6 explains how name lookup looks *outward* in all enclosing namespaces in case of a variable used with a function, but I'm having trouble finding the same for a variable definition at namespace scope.

Comment: @KerrekSB Unqualified name lookup is quite clearly for the function occurred in the user declared namespace. But I cant find the same subsequent for the name occurred in the variable member definition. It  confused me. Did you mean that for the function and variable definition unquailified name lookup is actually the same?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question:

> `int N::j=i` actual appears into the namespace scope. Hence the declaration `int i=2` is not visible for unqualified name lookup. Why does this declaration found?

Answer:

> Since `i` is not found in the `N` namespace, it is looked up in the global namespace. Had an `i` been there in the `N` namespace, that would have been used to initialize `N::j`.

Hope the following program clarifies your doubt.

```
#include <iostream>

namespace N 
{
   extern int j;
   extern int k;

   int x = 3;
}

int x = 2;
int y = 10;

int N::j = x; // N::x is used to initialize N::j
int N::k = y; // ::y is used to initialize N::k

int main()
{
   std::cout << N::j << std::endl;
   std::cout << N::k << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

```
3
10
```

**Update, in response to comment by OP**

What the standard is saying is that:

```
namespace N 
{
   extern int j;
}

int x = 2;

int N::j = x;
```

is equivalent to:

```
namespace N 
{
   extern int j;
}

int x = 2;

namespace N 
{
   int j = x;
}
```

The logic for lookup of`x` is same. If it is found within the same namespace `N`, it is used.  If `x` is not found in namespace `N`, it is searched for outward in the enclosing namespaces.

Comment: But in the standard said the `If a variable member of a namespace is defined outside of the scope of its namespace then any name that appears in the definition of the member (after the declarator-id) is looked up as if the definition of the member occurred in its namespace.`. In your example declaration of y is not visible from namespace N. Hence in the `int N::k = y;` y will no be found.

Comment: @CTAHOK3ABXO3A: `y` **is** visible.

Comment: +1 but you should reword that last sentence. If `x` is not found within the same namespace it is searched for outward in the enclosing namespaces. That's why [this code](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7a6055a28e247941) results in `j=2`, and not `j=4`

Comment: @Praetorian. Thanks for providing a better description. Updated the answer.

Comment: Nice explanation. I forgot that scopes of namespaces with the same namespace_id is concat.

Comment: @CTAHOK3ABXO3A I'm glad the explanation made sense.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be confused about how name lookup works on a basic level. Maybe a simple example helps:

```
#include <iostream>

void print(std::string const & s) { std::cout << "Boo: " << s << "\n"; }

namespace Foo
{
    std::string message = "Foo";

    void action() { print(message); }
}

int main() { Foo::action(); }
```

Clearly the name `print` is visible in the definition of `Foo::action`. Names from containing namespaces are visible in contained namespaces. There's nothing unusual about that.

The point of the rule you are quoting, and which R Sahu already demonstrated nicely, is that you can put the definition of a variable elsewhere from its declaration, and in that case any name appearing in the initializer is looked up in the namespace in which the variable is declared. Here's another example:

```
namespace Foo
{
    namespace Bar { int a = 10; }
    int b = 20;

    extern int c;
}

namespace Bar { int a = -20; }
int b = 5;

int Foo::c = Bar::a + b;  // uses Foo::Bar::a and Foo::b, NOT ::Bar::a or ::b

int main() { return Foo::c; }  // returns 30
```