# Why does unqualified name lookup find all overloaded declarations

Tags: c++, overloading, language-lawyer

Here is an example which I'm trying to understand how does unqualified name look up work for overloaded declarations:

```
int foo(char a){ return 0; }

namespace A
{
    int foo(int a){ return a; }
    int foo(){ return 2; }
    extern int j;
    extern int i;
}

int A::j=foo('a'); //97
int A::i=foo(); //2
```

It means that `int foo(char);` does not found by unqualified name look up but `int foo(int);` and `int foo()` can be found. So I assume that **unqualified name look up for overloaded declaration ends as soon as all overloaded declarations is found for the name.** I can't find this into the standard, I can find only the following (sec. 3.4.1):

> name look up ends as soon as a declaration is found for the name.

This quote doesn't say anything about overloaded declaration look up.

Comment: "... Name lookup may associate more than one declaration with a name if it finds the name to be a function name; the declarations are said to form a set
 of overloaded functions (13.1)..." (C++11 §3.4/1)

Answer (score 3):

You're mixing up *name lookup* with *overload resolution*. There is no such thing as "unqualified name look up for overloaded declaration". Name lookup and overload resolution are separate.

*Name lookup* means determining which scope the name is found in. Once that is completed, *overload resolution* determines which of the declarations visible in that scope should be used.

In your code, *name lookup* determines that `foo` means `A::foo`. Then *overload resolution* selects between `A::foo()` and `A::foo(int)`.  The `::foo` is not considered for overload resolution because it is not a definition of `A::foo`.

Another example:

```
namespace C { void f(); }
namespace B { void f(); void f(float); }
namespace C { void f(long); }

using namespace C;

int main()
{
    f(1.0);
}
```

When processing the line `f(1.0)`, *name lookup* sees `void f();` and stops. The result is that `f` means `C::f`.

Then *overload resolution* kicks in, and all declarations of `C::f` are considered for overload resolution. `void f(long)` is chosen.

Answer (score 1):

> In a declaration in which the *declarator-id* is a *qualified-id*, names used before the *qualified-id* being declared
>      are looked up in the defining namespace scope; names following the *qualified-id* are looked up in the scope
>         of the member’s class or namespace.

(C++11 §3.4.3/3)

So in both of

```
int A::j=foo('a');
int A::i=foo();
```

the name `foo` is looked up in the scope of `A` just because you have `A::j` and `A::i` to the left, in the declarator.

Note that if you do

```
int k = foo();
```

only the global `foo` will be found, and you'll get an error.

Comment: I know what scopes is searched during unqualified lookup. I asked quite another.

Comment: @DmitryFucintv I left a comment on the question. I'm not going to edit this answer because I think the details in the answer will be useful for other people who will see the question.

Answer (score 0):

You said

> It means that `int foo(char);` does not found by unqualified name look up but `int foo(int);` and `int foo()` can be found. So I assume that **unqualified name look up for overloaded declaration ends as soon as all overloaded declarations is found for the name.**

A similar question was asked in [another SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23941480/user-declared-namespace-member/23941748#23941748)

There is from 3.4.1/14:

> If a variable member of a namespace is defined outside of the scope of its namespace then any name that appears in the definition of the member (after the declarator-id) is looked up as if the definition of the member occurred in its namespace.

Your posted code is equivalent to:

```
int foo(char a){ return 0; }

namespace A
{
    int foo(int a){ return a; }
    int foo(){ return 2; }
    extern int j;
    extern int i;
}

namespace A
{
  int j=foo('a');
  int i=foo();
}
```

When the definitions and initializations are put under the namespace, it becomes clear why functions used to initialize the variables are looked up in namespace `A` first. If an unambiguous match can be found for a function in namespace `A`, the search for it stops. That means, when compiling the line,

```
int A::j=foo('a');
```

The lookup for `foo` starts in namespace `A`, is resolved to `int A::foo(int);` and the search for `foo` stops.

Hope this clears the confusion.

Answer (score -1):

In the standard (§3.4/1)

> Name lookup shall
>   find an unambiguous declaration for the name (see 10.2). Name lookup may associate more than one declaration with a name if it finds the name to be a function name; the declarations are said to form a set
>   of overloaded functions (13.1). Overload resolution (13.3) takes place after name lookup has succeeded.
>   The access rules (Clause 11) are considered only once name lookup and function overload resolution (if
>   applicable) have succeeded.

Which means the steps are as follows for methods:

1. First collect all the matching names
2. Do overload resolution
3. Check for accessibility

For method, name lookup does not return after finding *first match*, rather it searches for all matching names. It is clear from the statement *Name lookup may associate more than one declaration with a name if it finds the name to be a **function name***.

Comment: But name lookup ends as soon as a declaration is found for the name.

Comment: In the case of overloading name lookup does not ends if we found declaration for the name. It it continue to find all overloaded declarations.

Comment: You said that the first step is to collect all mathced names. But from the quote `name lookup ends as soon as a declaration is found for the name` implies that only one declaration can be matched for the name. I'm confused...

Comment: @DmitryFucintv, what is your question exactly? `int foo(char);` can not be found because it does not exist, nothing related to scope or name lookup. and your question about overload resolution is answered

Comment: @DmitryFucintv, *name lookup ends as soon as a declaration is found for the name* is a general case, the specific case for method lookup is also clearly described in the standard. *This quote doesn't say anything about overloaded declaration look up* is wrong

Comment: When we're finding `foo`'s declarations in the `namespace A` scope the `int foo()` will be found after the `int foo(int a)` will be found. But when `int foo(int a)` will be found unqualified name lookup must be end because `name lookup ends as soon as a declaration is found for the name`. But unqualified name lookup can found all overloaded declarartions in the current scope.

Comment: _the specific case for method lookup is also clearly described in the standard._ Where is it described? Can you give me a reference?